# Unable to transfer an axios response to a object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to transfer the result of a response to a characters object, but it throws an error:

> Cannot read property 'characters' of undefined

```
<script>
const axios = require("axios");
export default {
  data: () => ({
    characters:[],
  }),
  created() {
    axios
      .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then(function(response) {
        const resp = response.data.results;
        this.characters.push(resp);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
    
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hang on … there's no `characters` property on the object at all, only one you generate on demand when the `data` method is called.

Comment: `characters` is defined in the body of another function. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not referring to your vue instance, so there are some ways to fix it

Solution 1 arrow function

```js
    axios
      .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then(response => {
        const resp = response.data.results;
        this.characters.push(resp);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Or bind

```js
    axios
      .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then(function(response) {
        const resp = response.data.results;
        this.characters.push(resp);
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      }.bind(this));
```

Or you choose async / await

```
async created() {
  try {
     let { data } = await axios.get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
     this.characters.push(data.results);
  } catch(err) {
     console.log(err)
  }
},
```